# convert oracle hex string to actual string value

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hex

I have extracted data from Oracle Logminor and u need convert it into useful sql. below is data

```
SQL_REDO from logminer:
insert into "UNKNOWN"."OBJ# 74587"("COL 1","COL 2","COL 3","COL 4","COL 5","COL 6","COL 7","COL 8","COL 9") 
values (HEXTORAW('c12d'),HEXTORAW('c4032c362e'),HEXTORAW('c3042222'),HEXTORAW('c105'),HEXTORAW('c3394c44'),HEXTORAW('c108'),HEXTORAW('c108'),HEXTORAW('c109'),HEXTORAW('c10b'));

Required Value:
Insert Into Scott.Test_Table
Select 44,2435345,33333,4.1234,567567,6.766,7,8,10 From Dual;

So I need help with the conversion from the Hex value to the actual value, this is for all data types.

for example:
c12d = 44
c4032c362e = 2435345
etc
```

Below is java code which i tried to convert but it is not converting exactly hex to string

```
public class StringToHex{

  public String convertStringToHex(String str){

      char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

      StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
      for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]));
      }

      return hex.toString();
  }

  public String convertHexToString(String hex){

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

      //49204c6f7665204a617661 split into two characters 49, 20, 4c...
      for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){

          //grab the hex in pairs
          String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
          //convert hex to decimal
          int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
          //convert the decimal to character
          sb.append((char)decimal);

          temp.append(decimal);
      }
      System.out.println("Decimal : " + temp.toString());

      return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      StringToHex strToHex = new StringToHex();
      System.out.println("\n***** Convert ASCII to Hex *****");
      String str = "2435345";  
      System.out.println("Original input : " + str);

      String hex = strToHex.convertStringToHex(str);

      System.out.println("Hex : " + hex);

      System.out.println("\n***** Convert Hex to ASCII *****");
      System.out.println("Hex : " + hex);
      System.out.println("ASCII : " + strToHex.convertHexToString(hex));
  }
}
```

Please suggest the way how i can understand the Oracle hex code to convert it into actual string. as per above code it is not according to String which i mention above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution Please see this code

```
using System;

public class num2raw
{  
   public static void Main()
   {


        Decimal p_number = Decimal.Parse("44");
        string v_result = "";
        Int16 v_exponent;
        Int16 v_bcd;
        Decimal v_temp;

        if (p_number == 0) 
            v_result = "80";
        else if (p_number > 0) {
            v_temp = p_number;
            v_exponent = Convert.ToInt16(193 + Math.Floor(Math.Log(Convert.ToDouble(p_number),100)));

            while (v_temp != Math.Floor(v_temp))
                v_temp *= 100;

            while (v_temp % 100 == 0) 
                v_temp = Math.Floor(v_temp/100);

            while (v_temp > 0) {
                v_bcd = Convert.ToInt16(v_temp % 100);
                v_result = String.Format("{0:X2}", v_bcd+1) + v_result;
                v_temp = Math.Floor(v_temp/100);
            }

            v_result = String.Format("{0:X2}", v_exponent) + v_result;
        }
        else { // p_number < 0
            v_temp = -p_number;
            v_exponent = Convert.ToInt16(62 - Math.Floor(Math.Log(Convert.ToDouble(v_temp),100)));

            while (v_temp != Math.Ceiling(v_temp))
                v_temp *= 100;

            while (v_temp % 100 == 0) 
                v_temp = Math.Floor(v_temp/100);            

            while (v_temp > 0) {
                v_bcd = Convert.ToInt16(v_temp % 100);
                v_result = String.Format("{0:X2}", 101 -v_bcd) + v_result;
                v_temp = Math.Floor(v_temp/100);
            }

            v_result = String.Format("{0:X2}", v_exponent) + v_result;

            if (v_result.Length < 42)
                v_result = v_result + "66";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(v_result);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're extracting the raw values, but those are the binary representation of [the Oracle **number** datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313), which does not correspond to any data type in Java.

You can see where this value is coming from by using the UTL_RAW package:

```
select rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_from_number(44)) from dual;         -- C12D 
select rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_from_binary_integer(44)) from dual; -- 2C = 101100 = 44 
select rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('44')) from dual;            -- 3434 = ASCII "4" "4"
```

If you want to convert `C12D` from an Oracle number to a decimal representation, you can either use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER` or [you can do it the hard way](https://gotodba.com/2015/03/24/how-are-numbers-saved-in-oracle/):

```
C12D = 11000001 00101101
```

For the first byte, the first `1` bit means it's a positive number. That leaves `1000001 = 65`, and we subtract 64 to get 1, so the exponent is 100^1.

For the second byte, `00101101 = 45`, you subtract 1 to get 44. So the final number is `0.44 x 100^1`, or 44.

I'm not going to go into further decimal places or negative numbers, you can read that yourself.

I think you should just use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER`.

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_number(hextoraw('C12D')) from dual; -- 44
```

Comment: what if i want same in sql server ?

Comment: I want to apply this data in sql server if there is something same like `utl_raw.cast_to_number(hextoraw` to convert oracle hex then it will be fine

Comment: No, I don't think SQL Server has a built-in function to convert Oracle numbers from hex/binary. Extract the data from Oracle using a process that saves the data in a usable format.

Comment: So anything else ? i want to parse sql and to apply in sql server after making it useful statement in sql server level or something third party like java or c#